# Converting promise-based React app to redux-saga: how do I set React component variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm a beginner with redux-saga and as a task I thought I'd try to convert a large existing React app from Promises to redux-saga.  I'm making some progress, but one issue I came on is that when I used Promises I was able to set component-local variables depending on whether the promise fulfilled or rejected.  Now it seems I just "hand over" the request to redux-saga and never know (in the call site) whether it fulfilled or not, and now I don't know (within my component) whether it succeeded or not.

For example, let us say I have this promise-based call which fetches my user's games

```
getCurrentGamesForUser = (nickname, token) => {
    return logic.getGamesForUser(nickname, token)
      .then(currentGames => {
        this.needToUpdateGamesFlagFromSocketIO = false
        this.setState({currentGames})
        sessionStorage.setItem('currentGames', JSON.stringify(currentGames))
      })
      .catch(({message}) => this.onError(message))
  }
```

Here I'm setting the flag `this.needToUpdateGamesFlagFromSocketIO` -- as well as a `sessionStorage` variable -- if my promise succeeds.

Now, as I understand it, I would convert this to

```
 getCurrentGamesForUser = (nickname, token) => {
    this.props.dispatch(getCurrentGames(nickname,token))
  }
```

and this works fine.  If there's an error, that will be sent to the store from the saga and my component will reflect that.

But what do I do about the local flags and the session storage?  Do I need to add these to the store as well?  That seems a messy way to go, unless I had a separate store for each component, a local store for each component, which also seems messy.   I saw some discussion of a similar topic here, https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907, but there doesn't seem to be an answer.  I'm sure I'm missing the "redux way" of handling all this, and so would welcome any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-Saga is meant to offload all action based triggers outside component to a separate saga scope. So unfortunately there is no straightforward way to implement what you have requested. Although there are some suggested workarounds in the [issue](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907) tracker you have mentioned.

The primary aim of redux-saga was ease of management of side affects by offloading it to a separate execution context. One of the tradeoff, is communication can only happen through `component -> action -> saga -> store -> component`. Hence for the above requirement, I believe using redux-saga would be counterproductive.

That said, you can always use `redux-saga` in combination with other promise / callback based methods such as `redux-thunk`.

Usecases such as above would be better suited for callback based implementations while complete isolation of side effects to redux would be handled well with `redux-saga`.

Comment: How would one combine `redux-saga` with `redux-thunk`?  Simply put the thunks in the action creators, and maintain the sagas separately?  More importantly, perhaps, how would using thunks allow you to know whether the thunk was successful or not?  (I'm not that familiar with thunks)

Comment: Maintain thunks and sagas separately. `redux-thunk` allows you to return a function from an action creator, instead of a normal object. It even takes care to return the thunk’s return value from the dispatch, so you can chain Promises as long as you return them.
Would recommend reading : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#user-content-composition

Comment: I read the docs and it looks good.  But -- and perhaps I'm missing the obvious -- for the thunk to know when the async call is done, I need to put the async call in the thunk, and remove it from the saga, right?  And that kind of defeats the purpose of the saga. Is there another way to do it that I'm missing?  I found this, https://github.com/diegohaz/redux-saga-thunk, which would help, but am trying not to add packages.

Comment: If you need to maintain the execution state within the component, why do you need `redux-saga ` ? `redux-thunk` or your current implementation is good enough. Saga defeats the purpose. But still if you need to do some side effects apart from the thunk, you need to dispatch another action, that the saga will listen to

Comment: Basically because the team I'm joining asked me to learn redux-saga -- and I thought the shortest route to that would be to convert an existing project I have to use redux-saga.  That's how I ended up here.  The one fly in the ointment is this issue of maintaining some state local to the component, which requires you to know something about what happened to your side effect.  Of course keeping state in the component is sort of against what redux-saga is set up to do, but from my research (googling) I'm not the only one who wants to keep some data private, not in the store.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But as mentioned in the git thread, this is still an unsolved problem till now. Your only go is to look for some other third party library or derive those private data in `mapStateToProps` from the information stored in redux.

Comment: Agreed -- I'm also looking into https://github.com/diegohaz/redux-saga-thunk to see if it does what I want...